# Ordering the xAxis Category in JavaFX 8 BarChart

Tags: javafx

How can I sort or order the xAxis of the BarChart in JavaFX 8, when the xAxis though defined as a String, represents numbers.  For example:

```
@Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Bar Chart Sample");
    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final BarChart<String,Number> bc = 
        new BarChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);
    bc.setTitle("Country Summary");
    xAxis.setLabel("Number");       
    yAxis.setLabel("Value");

    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    series1.setName("Series-1");
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2",200));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("3",500));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("4",100));

    XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
    series2.setName("Series-2");
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("1",900));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2",150));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("3",50));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("4",700));

    Scene scene  = new Scene(bc,800,600);
    bc.getData().addAll(series1, series2);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Though this is a simplistic way of showing the problem, in my code am  generating the BarChart from a huge excel file. A snippet of the code am using is below:

```
final ObservableList<XYChart.Series<String,Number>> barChartData =      FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<XYBean>>> it = xyBean.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<XYBean>> entry = it.next();
                XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series<>();
                series.setName(entry.getKey());
                for (XYBean xybean : entry.getValue()) {
                    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(xybean.getxValue(), xybean.getyValue()));

                }

                barChartData.add(series);

            }
barChart.setData(barChartData);
```

Please help, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort the categories.

```
Collections.sort(xAxis.getCategories());
```

does **not work**, nevertheless.

One way **that works** looks like this:

```
// fill this whenever you add new data to the chart
private final Set<String> categories = new LinkedHashSet<>();

// after all data is added to the chart, sort the categories, set them manually and enable auto-ranging again (if needed)
final ObservableList<String> c = FXCollections.observableArrayList(categories);
Collections.sort(c);
xAxis.setCategories(c);
xAxis.setAutoRanging(true);
```

Comment: Two things to note: (a) getCategories is available in CategoryAxis - if you get it from chart, you must cast it first. (b) it's crucial to setCategories and then setAutoranging, otherwise the labels aren't sorted, but only the bars!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to get the categories from the xAxis, and sort them with a comparator. Although I was under the impression that a Category Axis does this on its own anyways.

```
ObservableList<String>list = xAxis.getCategories();
Comparator<String> byValue = (e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(e1), Integer.parseInt(e2));
xAxis.setCategories(list.sort(byValue));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried using a comparator, but probably I was doing it all wrong, please share the code how you achieve that, considering the snippet from my code?  
Thanks.

Comment: ObservableList<String>list = xAxis.getCategories(); This line doesn't seem to get anything, when I check the list size, its zero, am I missing something?     Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you're calling it after you're data has been loaded into the chart.

Comment: First, thanks so much for helping me on this one, but still not working. I have placed the code that you suggested right at the end, see below:                       Scene scene = new Scene(barChart, 400, 200);
                fxPanel.setScene(scene);
                ObservableList<String> list = xAxis.getCategories();
                 Comparator<String> byValue = (e1, e2) -> Double.compare(Double.parseDouble(e1), Double.parseDouble(e2));
                list.sort(byValue);      The list is sorted, but the barChart is not.

Comment: The output from the list is: list before sorting --- [1.0, 4.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 29.0, 30.0, 31.0, 0.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0]          list after sorting -----
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 29.0, 30.0, 31.0]

Comment: Not sure why that isn't working.  I guess try setting the categories to the new sorted list.

Comment: It has worked, I guess that was the missing part.   Thanks so much!